How do I set the language for Extbase repositories in a TYPO3 / Symfony CLI?
I regularly develop import/export commands that deal with multiple languages. I always use Extbase repositories and models, so I don't have to connect records manually or do other sketchy things.
I have my workarounds with setRespectSysLanguage to false and add the sysLanguageUid manually to every query, but I must have my customized methods that return the record in the language I need.
Isn't there a way in TYPO3 to set a specific language in a Symfony command, maybe via the language aspect, globally so that I don't have to have specialized methods for everything and I can switch to a different language, other than the default language, and fetch records from the repository in this language?

You could implement the following Method in your repository class:
public function setLanguage($langId)
{
    $querySettings = $this->createQuery()->getQuerySettings();
    $querySettings->setLanguageUid($langId);
    $this->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
}

And now you can set the language Id to your repository before fetching data. I.e. like this:
// LangId 2 i.e.
$langIdYouWant = 2;
$this->yourRepository->setLanguage($langIdYouWant);
$model = $this->yourRepository->findByAnythingYouWant('WhatYouWant');

Be aware, that the findByUid method will ignore the set languageId.
You can now pass the language Id to your cli command and change the langauage in the repo before doing things.
EDIT after first comment
If you need it a bit more automated you could do the following.
Implement an base class for your repositories that will be implemented by all your repositories like that:
class YourRepository extends YourBaseRepository
{
    // Do fancy repo stuff here....
}

In the base repository you can implement the initializeObject Method like this:
class YourBaseRepository extends Repository
{
    
    public function initializeObject() {
        parent::initializeObject();
        if(defined('CLI_IMPORT_LANGUAGE_UID')){
            $langId = constant('CLI_IMPORT_LANGUAGE_UID');
            $querySettings = $this->createQuery()->getQuerySettings();
            $querySettings->setLanguageUid($langId);
            $this->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
        }
    }

}

So now you can pass a language id to your CommandController when executing it. And set the language id as runtime constant.
define('CLI_IMPORT_LANGUAGE_UID', $langUid);

In that way the constant is only available for the import-routine of your command.
That should do the job.

Thank you. That's how I usually do it. The problem with this method is that as soon as it gets more complex, you have to apply this to all repositories, and all repositories have to have the correct language at any time, so the chance of an error is higher. This is fine for simple tasks, but for complex imports with many different repositories, you have to make sure that all your repositories have the correct language. I just thought maybe there is an easier way provided by the core that I missed.

Use DataHandler/QueryBuilder for imports in CLI not Extbase. Extbase is FE Context, CLI is BE context without being a web request context. You could "simulate FE context" along with all the stuff required to bootstrap FE context, including request(global), loading TypoScript (Extbase heavily uses TypoScript because it is FE context bound) etc. You will not find anything from the core to help you on CLI context with Extbase as Extbase is not designed to work in that area.

Yeah, but with the DataHandler/QueryBuilder, I can't use the existing models. This requires that I handle all the connections between the tables myself, which is way more work and time-consuming than using the repositories.
